# Make CSS Menu cover entire page

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make a menu that covers the entire page. So far it only shows one line. I would like the menu elements to center the page and not be on top.

This is a sample:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mxAhv

and the code
CSS

```
.menu-opener, .menu-opener:hover, .menu-opener.active, .menu-opener-inner, .menu-opener-inner::before, .menu-opener-inner::after, .menu, .menu.active {
  -webkit-transition: 250ms all;
  transition: 250ms all;
}

.menu-opener {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 64px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 2%;
  right: 1%;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  width: 64px;
}
.menu-opener:hover, .menu-opener.active {
  background: #231F20;
}

.menu-opener-inner {
  background: #000;
  height: .5rem;
  margin-left: .75rem;
  margin-top: 1.75rem;
  width: 2.5rem;
}
.menu-opener-inner::before, .menu-opener-inner::after {
  background: #000;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: .5rem;
  width: 2.5rem;
}

.menu-opener-inner::before {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-0.75rem);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-0.75rem);
  transform: translateY(-0.75rem);
}
.menu-opener-inner::after {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0.25rem);
  -ms-transform: translateY(0.25rem);
  transform: translateY(0.25rem);
}
.menu-opener-inner.active {
  background: transparent;
}
.menu-opener-inner.active::before {
    background: #fff;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0rem) rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: translateY(0rem) rotate(-45deg);
  transform: translateY(0rem) rotate(-45deg);
}
.menu-opener-inner.active::after {
    background: #fff;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-0.5rem) translateX(0rem) rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-0.5rem) translateX(0rem) rotate(45deg);
  transform: translateY(-0.5rem) translateX(0rem) rotate(45deg);
}

.menu {
  background: #231F20;
  color: transparent;
  height: 64px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 2%;
 right: 1%;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  width: 0rem;
  z-index: -1;
}
.menu.active {
  width: -webkit-calc(100% - 2rem);
  width: calc(100% - 2rem);
}
.menu.active .menu-link {
  color: white;
}

.menu-inner {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;
  -ms-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
  height: 100%;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  margin-left: 4rem;
  padding: 0;
}

.menu-link {
  color: transparent;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex: 1 1 auto;
  -ms-flex: 1 1 auto;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: 100;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.menu-link li {
  margin: auto;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .menu {
    height: auto;
  }
  .menu-inner {
    display: block;
  }
  .menu-link {
    padding: 10px 0;
    font-size: 1.2em;
  }
  .menu.active {
    width: -webkit-calc(100% - 0.5rem);
    width: calc(100% - 0.5rem);
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean you want the menu to cover the entire page?

Comment: yea..like when i click on the menu it covers the whole page. Instead of being just in one line and the menu elements should be centered to the middle of the page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yCiLm.](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yCiLm)
I added the following in the .menu.active definition:

```
.menu.active {
  width: -webkit-calc(100% - 2rem);
  width: calc(100% - 2rem);
  height: calc(100% - 1rem);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
 .menu.active {
     height: 100%;
 }
```